# Regexp - Delete the one word before XXX, remove XXX too

Tags: c#, regex

I need to remove a word XXX in a string and also one word before XXX.

How I can do that with C# Regexp?

Comment: What have you attempted already?

Comment: The first occurrence of that word plus the preceding word, or all occurrences of that word and their preceding word?

Comment: I need the first occurrence

Comment: what if XXX is a first word in a string? Should it be deleted?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a blog site where you keep coming back for updates.  Your question has been answered.  If you need more support, open a new question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please havea look at this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48224194/net-regex-remove-one-word-and-one-word-before-match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a single regex replacement:

```
string input = @"Hello World XXX Goodbye XXX Rabbit!";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\s*\w+\s+(?:XXX|xxx)");  // or maybe [Xx]{3}
string result = rgx.Replace(input, "", 1);
Console.WriteLine(result);

Hello Goodbye XXX Rabbit!
```

### Demo

This replacement only would target `XXX` for removal if it be preceded by a word (one character or more).  Explore the demo to see how it would behave with various inputs.

We can also make the search pattern case insensitive via this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\s*\w+\s+XXX", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                                       ^^^^^ add this
```

Comment: You are the man!!! Saved a lot of my time :) Is it possible to make XXX word case insensitive?

Comment: @Vnuuk Use an alternation `(?:XXX|xxx)`.  If _any_ X letter could have any case, then use `[Xx]{3}`.

Comment: Or may be `new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`

Comment: That's cool! But what if we have not XXX but word "SUPERWORD" ?

Comment: @A.Gladkiy Maybe that would be best, but I was worried that maybe the OP only might have a portion of the pattern that he wanted to be case insensitive.  In that case, making the whole pattern case insensitive would not work.

Comment: Yep - doesn't work..

Comment: @Vnuuk See the comment by A. Gladkiy above.

Comment: new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) - doesn't work :(

Comment: @Vnuuk Check my updated answer.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case :( http://prntscr.com/hzdwtj

Comment: Could you please update your demo?

Comment: [Updated demo](http://rextester.com/TLMJ21360) showing that matching on `XXX` (all caps) matches to `xxx` in input string.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! I found why it didn't work on my string.. "DDD K.D,M/ xXx GHI". It's because of special symbol... "/".. can I escape it somehow?

Comment: @Vnuuk Here is one option: http://rextester.com/DHLS40753 .  This is my last comment.  Thank you for participating in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you kindly adjust it please, so it removes "D.E," also - http://prntscr.com/hze1b0

Answer (score -3):

U can use the replace method :

```
      String s = "aaa bbb";
      s = s.Replace("a", "")

// The example displays the following output:
//       The initial string: 'aaa bbb'
//       The final string: 'bbb'
```

Or use a Regex in replace :

```
tmp = s.Replace(n, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", "");
```

Comment: Sorry, but in your case I know "bbb" only.. plus I need regular expression..

Comment: Answer edited with a regex in replace method...
Regex only can't remove characters... you need replace