# Remove one word and one word before match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

One word before match could be a set of any symbols.. like "D.E,F/".

I have a regex:

```
@"\s*[\w/]+\s+XXX"
```

Input example: This is KKK M.D,D/ xXx PPP
Output example: This is KKK PPP

So I need to remove 1 word before XXX also remove XXX (ignoring case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regexp - Delete the one word before XXX, remove XXX too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223287/regexp-delete-the-one-word-before-xxx-remove-xxx-too)

Comment: @ВІТАЛІЙМаковейчук There is a difference between this and [Regexp - Delete the one word before XXX, remove XXX too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223287/regexp-delete-the-one-word-before-xxx-remove-xxx-too) post: `D.E,F/` is not "word", it is a sequence of non-whitespace chars.

Comment: Great solution! Marked as answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `D.E,F/` is not a word, it is a sequence of non-whitespace chars. `[\w/]+` is a character class matching word and `/` chars, and if you plan to further add chars here, the pattern might get too long and cumbersome.

It seems more convenient to use the `\S+` pattern to match any 1+ chars other than whitespace:

```
\s*\S+\s+XXX
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs*%5CS%2B%5Cs%2BXXX&i=This%20is%20KKK%20M.D%2CD%2F%20xXx%20PPP&r=&o=i). Use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to perform a case insensitive match, or prepend the pattern with `(?i)` inline modifier.

In C#:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)\s*\S+\s+XXX", string.Empty);
```

**Pattern details**

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive inline modifier
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
- `XXX` - an `XXX` substring.